# Expo VS React Native CLI regarding performance when accessing a native device feature e.g. location

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

Expo provides an easier way to access Camera, Location and other native device features compared to React Native CLI. But, does this compromise any performance? are there any downsides accessing those features from Expo?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using expo-bare in production more than 2 years in different applications. There are many reason to add expo to your next project, for example SDKs(camera, barcodescanner, iap, location etc.) are up to date, and all gradle/xcode builds are handled by expo also OTA update is built-in.

No downsides regarding performance or bundle size I have experienced by far.